# Cpanel and WHM will not save the passwords in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cpanel, whm

When trying to login on a cPanel or WHM server, the browser never asks if I want to save the login credentials (user/password). This only happens with Chrome (I can save password perfectly with FF and Opera).

Answer (score 2):

This issue with Chrome is not new, nor cPanel specific, it's actually an ongoing issue that cPanel has been attempting to work around for some time now. More on the issue here:

[Password not remembered when login form uses XHR or equivalent - code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43219)

Suggested workaround by cPanel Developers:

1) Disable JavaScript, login, then logout, then re-enable JavaScript. Subsequent logins will be auto-filled.
2) Install a Chrome addon that extends Chrome’s ability to save passwords.
3) Use a non-WebKit browser.

I have tried item #1 and it works as expected. On first hitting the login page with javascript disabled, you're greeted with a warning, ignore that and type in your login details and login. Once you get in, Chrome then asks if you'd like to save your password, choose yes. Now logout. Enable Javscript again, try WHM login page. You'll see your username and password already filled in.

Hope that helps.

(originally on: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/cpanel-whm-not-save-passwords-chrome-277232-p2.html)